# How to write symbols "<" ">" in a XML File with C#

Tags: c#, xml

I need help with my task, right now i'm developing a website with C# and I need to create XML labels automatically, of a text in a special label, right I get all the data and i add it in an arrays and i create all the sentence, right now i'm fine with my result.

My result is like these lines:

```
double M = <M>2.0</M>
double C = <C>0.59</C>
double D = <D>0.48</D>
double E = <E>0.69</E>
```

But right now my problem is the next, when i try to save the information to the XML file, I have two issues.

1.- I cant write the declaration of the variables between labes.
2.- When i save the information in to the XML, the symbols of "<" and ">", has change for (`&gt;` and `&lt;`).

There is a way to save the result:

```
double M = <M>2.0</M>
double C = <C>0.59</C>
double D = <D>0.48</D>
double E = <E>0.69</E>
```

Or these it's imposible?

Thanks for your time

Comment: sorry the text editor change some symbols,   2.- When i save the information in to the XML, the symbols of "<" and ">", has change for (& lt; and & gt;).

Comment: The angle brackets are special to XML and must be encoded to be treated as data. Are you trying to save the list of declarations as individual elements in your XML file? In other words, what is the structure of the XML document you are trying to save?

Comment: @Suncat2000, hi the strucure of my XML is the next

<VariablesAndFunctions>
<Constraint>
double M = <M>2.0</M>
double C = <C>0.59</C>
</Constraint>
</VariablesAndFunctions>

Comment: @LauroMeza, what you've described isn't a valid XML. You might want to reconsider it if possible

Comment: @YuriG ok thank you, i was thinking, it was a invalid format, jejeje, but i will try to do it in another way with XML Valid.

Comment: It is valid XML. Paste it into the validator here [ http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp ] and it says "no errors found".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what your issue is here - presumably it's something to do with how you're putting the XML together. I've just knocked this up quickly and it works just fine:

```
class Program
{
    static string GetData()
    {
        return "double M = <M>2.0</M>" +
               "double C = <C>0.59</C>" +
               "double D = <D>0.48</D>" +
               "double E = <E>0.69</E>";
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        var variablesAndFunctions = doc.CreateElement("VariablesAndFunctions");
        doc.AppendChild(variablesAndFunctions);

        var constraints = doc.CreateElement("Constraints");
        constraints.InnerXml = GetData();
        variablesAndFunctions.AppendChild(constraints);

        Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The key line is setting the `InnerXml` property of an element to the Xml content that was returned from the `GetData` function. Should work fine for you too.

Comment: Thank you Richard, with your help I fix my issue, the code works for me ;D

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
<root><![CDATA[
double M = <M>2.0</M>
double C = <C>0.59</C>
double D = <D>0.48</D>
double E = <E>0.69</E>
]]></root>
```

Then do this in your code:

```
XElement root = new XElement("root", new XCData(@"
double M = <M>2.0</M>
double C = <C>0.59</C>
double D = <D>0.48</D>
double E = <E>0.69</E>
"));
```